# Is it appropriate to mention a relatable company blog post when you're asked about the company?

Tags: interviewing

From past interview experience, I'm always asked *what can you tell us about the company?* or a similar question.

To prepare for it I usually browse the about us page on the company website, but I noticed that several of these companies have blogs that they use to keep clients up to date with events or share an interesting idea.

If you find a post relatable, for example, one of the companies I'm currently researching does community outreach, I have past experience with this when I volunteered, so would it be okay to bring this up during the interview?

Comment: @Fattie don't answer in comments

Comment: Yes, it's appropriate, at least the place where I work, I was in a similar position, and I now organize and plan all the community events.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, absolutely! They’ll appreciate the fact that your interests align with the company’s values and that you took the time to do thorough research.

Comment: Maybe note that it's better to keep it simple -- don't go overboard, as Fattie says above.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in college I took a class that helped us prepare for interviews and it was encouraged to research the company. It shows them your interest in the company and they'll be glad to hear you can relate to them.

Answer (score 1):

Mention: yes, but make it somehow clear that which was just a small part of your research. Also make sue that while you show a positive attitude toward the blogs, you keep enough distance. While companies like motivated people, they also don't like people with no sense for real life.